# Who designed monokai color scheme?

Tags: color, copyright, history

I admire Monokai color scheme. Did the makers of Sublime Text design it or is it in use before Sublime Text arrived?

The second part of the question is that can I freely copy it for my own editor or does anybody have copyright on it?

Comment: Sounds like something you should ask the Sublime Text team about.

Comment: I don't usually necrobump posts like this, but: https://www.monokai.pro/

Comment: @Roberrrt: Comments do not bump anything on this site and post necromancy is absolutely okay. However, please do not just drop a link in a comment, but instead post a proper answer, or edit the question, or tell us why that link is otherwise relevant.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Well, the link isn't a new answer, it's merely more of the story + a premium version of the current color scheme.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [oldest post about it I could find](https://web.archive.org/web/20161107090516/http://www.monokai.nl/blog/2006/07/), Monokai was developed by Wimer Hazenberg in 2006 for Textmate. It has since been distributed among all sorts of other text editors.

You can freely copy it for your own editor as there is [no real way*](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/58545/23061) to copyright a color scheme. To be absolutely sure you could email him, the address is on the site.

Comment: If Apple was able to patent round corners, I feel like anything is possible.